# In Fedora, how can I see a log of mounts to Samba shares made by clients?

Tags: linux, samba, fedora, mount

I am working with an inherited Fedora server that has dozens (maybe hundreds) of Perl scripts. Many of these mount then unmount network locations. So, the mounts are not discoverable with the mount command. We are about to move some network storage to other servers. Is there a way to pull from logs everything that has been mounted / unmounted in the past 30 days? Is mount activity typically logged?

**EDIT**
I was unclear in my original question. Updating to help the future.
The shares are all via Samba; added that to the question.

Comment: There are many types of network file systems that can be mounted. Which are of your concern? Are they fuse mounts or kernel mounts? In most cases, the client does little system logging if at all. Usually the server logs which clients are mounting.

Comment: Thanks @gogators. I had not thought about looking from the server side. I could just look on those servers we are moving, also Fedora. How/can I do that?

Comment: Well, log into the servers and check the log files that the particular server uses. You still haven't mentioned what services you're concerned with (NFS, GFS, beegfs, etc.).

Comment: Maybe you should ask two separate questions for each. "How to check which clients mount my NFS server?", for example.

Answer (score 1):

Samba logs incoming connections.
`sudo smbstatus -v` at the comand line gives a report of those connections